# SQL Server not using index

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I'm trying to write a query in SQL Server, but it's doing a table scan on a table with about 30 million rows (TGS_INFO), so the query runs very slowly.

The actual query is more complex but I've reduced it to a simpler version that still exhibits the same issue.

```
SELECT DISTINCT UNIT_ITEMS.DBKEY,
    UNIT_ITEMS.ID,
    UNIT_ITEMS.LOCATION1,
    UNIT_ITEMS.LOCATION2
FROM UNIT_ITEMS
INNER JOIN TGS.dbo.TGS_INFO
ON UNIT_ITEMS.UNIT_ID = TGS_INFO.UNIT_ID AND
    UNIT_ITEMS.ITEM_ID = TGS_INFO.ITEM_ID AND
    UNIT_ITEMS.LOCATION1 = TGS_INFO.LOCATION1 AND
    UNIT_ITEMS.LOCATION2 = TGS_INFO.LOCATION2
```

Here is the execution plan.

```
StmtText
  |--Sort(DISTINCT ORDER BY:([DbName].[dbo].[UNIT_ITEMS].[DBKEY] ASC, [DbName].[dbo].[UNIT_ITEMS].[ITEM_ID] ASC, [DbName].[dbo].[UNIT_ITEMS].[LOCATION1] ASC, [DbName].[dbo].[UNIT_ITEMS].[LOCATION2] ASC))
       |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([DbName].[dbo].[UNIT_ITEMS].[UNIT_ID], [DbName].[dbo].[UNIT_ITEMS].[ITEM_ID], [DbName].[dbo].[UNIT_ITEMS].[LOCATION1], [DbName].[dbo].[UNIT_ITEMS].[LOCATION2])=([Expr1008], [Expr1009], [Expr1010], [Expr1011]), RESIDUAL:([DbName].[dbo].[UNIT_ITEMS].[UNIT_ID]=[Expr1008] AND [DbName].[dbo].[UNIT_ITEMS].[ITEM_ID]=[Expr1009] AND [DbName].[dbo].[UNIT_ITEMS].[LOCATION1]=[Expr1010] AND [DbName].[dbo].[UNIT_ITEMS].[LOCATION2]=[Expr1011]))
            |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([DbName].[dbo].[UNIT_ITEMS]))
            |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1008]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[TGS].[dbo].[TGS_INFO].[UNIT_ID],0), [Expr1009]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(50),[TGS].[dbo].[TGS_INFO].[ITEM_ID],0), [Expr1010]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(50),[TGS].[dbo].[TGS_INFO].[LOCATION1],0), [Expr1011]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[TGS].[dbo].[TGS_INFO].[LOCATION2],0)))
                 |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([TGS].[dbo].[TGS_INFO]))
```

TGS_INFO and UNIT_ITEMS both have nonclustered indexes on UNIT_ID and ITEM_ID. As mentioned, TGS_INFO has about 30 million rows but they are evenly distributed around about a thousand different UNIT_IDs. UNIT_ITEMS always contains only one UNIT_ID.

Here are the indexes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UNIT_ID_ITEM_ID] ON [dbo].[TGS_INFO] 
(
    [UNIT_ID] ASC,
    [ITEM_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UNIT_ID_ITEM_ID] ON [dbo].[UNIT_ITEMS] 
(
    [UNIT_ID] ASC,
    [ITEM_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

As I mentioned in the comments, all the columns are VARCHAR(50) in TGS_INFO. All the columns in UNIT_ITEMS are ints.

For the record, I didn't design the schema of TGS_INFO.

Comment: You can only have one clustered index per table. What is the column order of your indices?

Comment: Right, the hash seems wrong. Also did you try without DISTINCT? Is that DISTINCT really necessary?

Comment: Do your data types match in all columns you're matching?  I don't see why it would be doing an implicit data conversion.  What if you move `UNIT_ITEMS.LOCATION1 = TGS_INFO.LOCATION1 AND UNIT_ITEMS.LOCATION2 = TGS_INFO.LOCATION2` to the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @njk sorry! I meant nonclustered indexes. You probably can tell this is an area I'm not very familiar with.

Comment: @Tmdean Can you please update your question with the exact indexes?

Comment: @BaconBits They don't match, all the data types in TGS_INFO are varchar(50).

Comment: Are your 2 tables coming from different databases?

Comment: @MicSim Yes, two different databases running on the same instance of SQL Server.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I tried it without the DISTINCT and had the same issue.

Comment: Not matching the data types is bad, you should fix that immediately. Fields that will be part of a join should almost always be the same datatype. You can only performance improve bad design so much.

Comment: @BaconBits, you had the correct answer - if I cast the columns in UNIT_ITEMS to varchar in the join it uses the indexes. If you write this up as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Besides @usr's answer below, which **IS** the answer, I would add that an index on these columns will get very large and isn't as fast as one on let's say an `int` or `bigint` column (or even GUID). You can consider adding a surrogate key to one of the tables and match on that instead of all these 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice the execution plan shows the following:

```
|--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1008]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[TGS].[dbo].[TGS_INFO].[UNIT_ID],0), [Expr1009]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(50),[TGS].[dbo].[TGS_INFO].[ITEM_ID],0), [Expr1010]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(50),[TGS].[dbo].[TGS_INFO].[LOCATION1],0), [Expr1011]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[TGS].[dbo].[TGS_INFO].[LOCATION2],0)))
```

I can't think of a good reason for the query engine to do an implicit data type conversion on these columns unless the data types between the two tables don't match on the columns you're using for the join.

You may also try moving `UNIT_ITEMS.LOCATION1 = TGS_INFO.LOCATION1 AND UNIT_ITEMS.LOCATION2 = TGS_INFO.LOCATION2` to the `WHERE` clause since they're not covered by an index.  The query engine is typically smart enough to account for this, but it's something to try.

Comment: Moving stuff to the where clause is not something that works on SQL Server. This trick is mainly useful on RDBMSs with weak query optimizers like MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't include `LOCATION1` and `LOCATION2` in your indexes the join cannot be satisfied from an index alone. Add these columns to the indexes on both tables.

You probably have to include all other columns that are referenced in your query, too.

Comment: UNIT_ID, ITEM_ID, LOCATION1, and LOCATION2 is a candidate key on the TGS_INFO table, so creating an index on that seems superfluous to me.

Comment: But you would be wrong. All FKs should be indexed. All potential keys should have a unique index on them as a group even if they are not being used as the PK. Only the official PK gets an index automatically. You can do it in one composite index.

Comment: I defer to your expertise on database design, but the issue in my particular case was that I hadn't checked that the columns that I was joining were the same data type. Adding more columns to the indexes wouldn't have fixed my issue.

Comment: @Tmdean was it fixed by fixing the data type? It might be the case that you still need to additional columns.

Comment: @usr Yes, it was fixed by fixing the data types in TGS_INFO.